# android onstop method cause force close

Tags: android, android-activity, playback, forceclose

here's my code below.
I have a meidaplayer in my app. if the user play the music then leave the activity all things are right, but when the user leave the activity without playing the music it cause the force close.

what's the problem?

```
public class Elementary1Activity extends Activity implements Runnable, OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        private SeekBar seekBar;
        private ImageButton startMedia;
        private ImageButton pauseMedia;
        private MediaPlayer mp;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.elementary1);             

            TextView title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1);
            TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
            title1.setTypeface(font);
            tx1.setTypeface(font);

            AudioControl();    



        }



        public void AudioControl(){
            seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarnew2);
            startMedia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbuttonnew2);
            pauseMedia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pausebuttonnew2);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
            startMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
            pauseMedia.setOnClickListener(this); 
        }



        public void run() {
            int currentPosition= 0;
            int total = mp.getDuration();
            while (mp!=null && currentPosition<total) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }            
                seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
            }
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            pauseMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            startMedia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (v.equals(startMedia)) {
                if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) return;
                if(seekBar.getProgress() > 0) {
                    mp.start();
                    return;
                }
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Elementary1Activity.this, R.raw.e1);
                mp.start();            

                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                new Thread(this).start();
            }

            if (v.equals(pauseMedia) && mp!=null) {
                mp.pause();
                pauseMedia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                startMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }       

        }



        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser) mp.seekTo(progress);

        }

        public void onStop() {
               super.onStop();
               mp.stop();
            }
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception on the force close? I think you should check that the mp is not null, and surround your line of code with a try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read Your code wright, If the user leaves Your Activity, that means the user uses the back button or do something else that makes the app stop, right? If yes, I think the problem is, that You don´t initialize Your MediaPlayer at this time. You are first initializing this MediaPlayer on Button Click, but in onStop() You are stopping a not initialized MediaPlayer. Initialize Your MediaPlayer in onCreate():

```
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.elementary1);             

        TextView title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1);
        TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");
        title1.setTypeface(font);
        tx1.setTypeface(font);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Elementary1Activity.this, R.raw.e1);


        AudioControl();    



    }
```

I haven´t tested Your code, but if this doesn´t work there is still another error, which I hadn´t search for. But this is definitely wrong.